# Integrating jmeter with appium

Tags: jmeter, appium, performance-testing, integrate

Can we integrate appium with jmeter for performance testing

I need to do performance testing for native mobile apps. Is there any way that I can integrate the appium with jmeter so I can generate the scripts for the same to generate load or capture server metrics

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate JMeter with Appium quite easily by:

- putting [Appium Java Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client) with all its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- restarting JMeter
- adding [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and writing your Appium code in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

and generate scripts for the same but you won't be able to "generate load" for the same because each instance of [AppiumDriver](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html) can only control one device (or emulator) at a time so in order to simulate 100 users you will need either 100 real devices or 100 emulators, moreover it will be quite tricky to collect and correlate performance metrics. So I would rather recommend simulating your application network footprint using relevant JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) than trying to conduct the load using Appium.